# Gridview: editing after searching

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, data-binding, sqldatasource

MY search button is linked to a GridvieW, which has an edit button on every row. When I press search button, data changes and a databind() occurs.
After that, If I try to use the edit button it displays another row to edit, not the selected one(biggest problem).Both buttons work well when tested separately, but not one after another. I solved that removing `GridView1.DataBind()` from edit button event, but then It will require 2 clicks to display the edit template(another problem).

EDIT: I guess teh problem is in the search button. Can you give a good search code that doesn't depend of sqldatasource?

```
'Where data is loaded into GV
Dim SqlDataSource1 As New SqlDataSource

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [TABLE]"
    SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = "Conn String"

    If Not IsPostBack Then   

        Dim conn As New SqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = con.GetConnectionString
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [AREA], [LEADER_USER] FROM [AREA]"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = conn
    conn.Open()
    Dim adpt As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    adpt.Fill(ds)
    GridView1.DataSource = ds
    GridView1.DataBind()
    conn.Close()
    End If

End Sub

'Search button
Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    Try
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id LIKE @id"
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Clear()
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(New Parameter("id", DbType.String, "%" + txtSearch.Text + "%"))
        GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1
        GridView1.DataBind()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub

'Edit button
Protected Sub EditRow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEditEventArgs)

    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" BackColor="#D9ECFF" 
                                        style="height: 20px; width: 186px" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" BackColor="#0066cc" 
                                        BorderColor="#0066cc" BorderStyle="Outset" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
                                        style=" height: 26px; width: 56px" Text="Search"  />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" OnRowEditing="EditRow" 
OnRowCancelingEdit="CancelEditRow" DataKeyNames="AREA" DataMember="DefaultView">

  <Columns>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="AREA" HeaderText="AREA" ReadOnly="True" 
                                        SortExpression="AREA" />                                   

      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LEADER_USER" SortExpression="LEADER_USER">
                     <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("leader_user")%></ItemTemplate>
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txtleaderuser" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("leader_user")%>'/>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>

       <asp:TemplateField>                                    
           <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:ImageButton ID="editButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" 
                                                ImageUrl="images/pencil1.png" Text="Edit" ToolTip="Edit" />
            </ItemTemplate>
             <EditItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Button ID="BtnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" 
                                                Text="Update" />
                   <asp:Button ID="BtnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                                                Text="Cancel" />
              </EditItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>

      </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Please help me. How are these 2 gridview functionalities supposed to be coded to work together? This is the only way I know how to do this, but any idea is ok for me if it works. If you are a C# guy, you ca use a C#-to VB converter:
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: You're so close to using ADO.NET (SqlCommand, SqlConnection, etc), why not just go all the way and get rid of the SqlDataSource?  I think what's happening in your edit is that the changes you made to the SqlDataSource in your Search aren't persisting.  What does your markup look like for the `SqlDataSource1`?

Comment: Excuse me, I don't know how to do it without SQldatasource, if you can show me it would be great. And there's is no asp code for SqlDataSource1, it is declared in code behind as you can see.

Comment: show your gridview markup also

Comment: @phalanx I do this kind of thing all the time and it works with one click. Please note what parts of your table/SQL code you want to search on as well (full column names in the table not *).

Comment: possible duplicate of [GridView Edit Button Requires 2 Clicks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724395/gridview-edit-button-requires-2-clicks)

Comment: 1. I use complete field names in my code, I just put "select * from table" here as example.
2. Yeah, that topic is mine, but later I realized the problem was not solved completely, because it conflicts with the search funcionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
  fill_grid()
        {
// populate your grid
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

       cmd.CommandText = " your select statement  ";


       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       cmd.Connection = this.sqlConnection1;
       this.yourConnection .Open();
       SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       adpt.Fill(ds);
       yourGrid.DataSource = ds;
       yourGrid.DataBind();

       this.sqlConnection1.Close();
    }
```

Then hook to the button click event of your search button like this :

```
 yourButton_Click ((object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           GridViewRow clickedRow = ((Button)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

    //Then find your parameter from your textbox in the clicked row 

           TextBox yourbox  = (TextBox)clickedRow.FindControl("your_box");

           //Here is where you would all your search logic whatever that is 

       }
```

Then you could still use your row_updating event independently of the search button click event.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't explained it properly:  search button is outside the grid and I don't need to click any row just to perform the search. Markup is above. Anyways, thanks for the fill_grid() part.

Comment: oh in that case you can just put the fill_grid() in your button click event for your search button

Comment: No, doesn't work. I copy-pasted  the fill_grid() code and added parameters, this way: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", TextBox1.Text), no results.

Comment: you have to do this 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text ;

Comment: How to add "%" characters inside a parameter(so my search performs LIKE '%id%') and send it to the command? With sqldatasource it is: SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(New Parameter("id", DbType.String, "%" + TextBox1.Text + "%"))

Answer (score 0):

you can add Where statement in page_load by if command and delete where in btnSearch_Click function. like this

```
if (txtSearch.Text.length()>0)
  SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand += "WHERE id LIKE @id"
```

then it works properly