# ASP.NET GridView requires two clicks of edit command - why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

Firstly, I realise the question of how to avoid two clicks has been asked multiple times with ths same answer - "re-bind the gridview" (eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724395/gridview-edit-button-requires-2-clicks?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206983/putting-a-gridview-row-in-edit-mode-programmatically)). However I'm after an explanation of **WHY** this occurs and if there's an alternative solution.

When using a Gridview, clicking the *Edit* button once fires the `OnRowEditing` event, yet makes no visual changes to the gridview, upon clicking for a second time, the `OnRowEditing` executes again, but this time on return the GridView row is now editable and has the *Update* and *Cancel* buttons.

If within the `OnRowEditing` method there is a manual `DataBind()` of the `gridview`, then a second click is not required.

**Why is this occuring?**

So, the scenario:

**GridView:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMain" runat="server" 
    OnRowEditing="gvMain_RowEditing" 
    OnRowCancelingEdit="gvMain_RowCancelingEdit" 
    OnRowUpdating="gvMain_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" EditText="Edit" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="location" HeaderText="Location" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**CodeBedhind:**

```
protected void gvMain_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gvMain.EditIndex = i;
}
```